# Delete duplicated rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, duplicates

I need to solve this problem for an application to delete duplicates spread over two SQL tables.

- t1 (t_ID, t_pID, ...)
- p2 (p_ID, p_Field1, p_Field2, ...)

`p_Field1` and `p_Field2` can be NULL

Normally I'd have a row in t1 that has connected one or more rows in p2. The users have created dirty data by creating different rows on t1 that have connected rows in p2 that have the same p_Field1 p_Field2

I need to find all the duplicate rows with these conditions

- I join t1 and p2 on t1.t_pID = p2.p_ID
- I made this query to find all the groups on both the fields

Query:

```
select p2.p_Field1, p2.p_Field2
from t1
inner join p2 on t1.t_pID = p2.p_ID
group by p2.p_Field1, p2.p_Field2
having count(*) > 1
```

Am I considering only the groups that have BOTH the fields equal?

How can I cover all the combinations?

How about the NULL values?

Thank you very much anyone who could help me a little

Comment: I think before and after data would be quite helpful.

Comment: Fire that select query and look at the result set w/o sample data; this will be a guess work. That said IF result-set gets you exactly what you are looking to delete THEN substitute the SELECT for DELETE. (2) Which brings to problem 2 you have to delete from 2 seperate tables. Can be solved by inserting resultset of 1 into a TEMP Table and join your two respective tables to TEMP table to delete by.

Comment: If this is about looking for dups of p_Field1 + p_Field2 values in p2, then don't join t1 in the mix.